# How many times can you call the github public api?

Tags: api, github

I am trying to build an application that will call the following public api:

https://api.github.com/repos/timothyylim/moscow-road/issues

thousands of times a day, is this possible?

I've tried reading through the documentation:

https://developer.github.com/v3/#increasing-the-unauthenticated-rate-limit-for-oauth-applications

But I've tested it on my browser and I can definitely call refresh the page with that url more than 60 times that is apparently the limit.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thousands of times a day? Why so much? Can you cache it?

Comment: I could cache it, but if there are hundreds of changes happening it would end up being quite a lot. I'm just trying to see what the upper bound is.

Answer (score 1):

From the **[GitHub Developer Documentation.](https://developer.github.com/v3/)**

> For requests using Basic Authentication or OAuth, you can **make up to
>   5,000 requests per hour.** For unauthenticated requests, the rate limit
>   allows you to make up to **60 requests per hour.** Unauthenticated
>   requests are associated with your IP address, and not the user making
>   requests. Note that the Search API has custom rate limit rules.

Comment: I saw that but I tested it and I can definitely hit that url more than 60 times. Perhaps I'm not understanding something here?

Comment: Are you using OAuth?  If not, maybe the API response is just giving you the same thing.

Comment: I am not using OAuth. It should return an error if I have gone over the limit (according to the docs).

Comment: That is weird.  Maybe a github support ticket?